# Rational solutions for quadratic equations in two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, rational-numbers

Consider the following quadratic equation where $a, b > 0$ are integers:

- $x_2^2 = x_1^2 - ax_1 + b^2$

I am looking for the rational solutions of the above equation satisfying the following conditions:

- $0 < x_1 < \frac{a}{2}$
- $\sqrt{b^2 - \frac{a^2}{4}} < x_2 < b$
- $2b > a$

Now consider the following conjectures:

- **Conjecture 1**: There are infinitely many rational values of $x_1, x_2$ satisfying the above equation for **each** possible positive integer values of $a, b$.
- **Conjecture 2**: If the Conjecture 1 is true, for a given integers $a, b$, the rational values of $x_1, x_2$ satisfying the above equation form a dense set.

Questions:

- Are the above conjectures true ? Are there any similar known conjectures or results ?
- If the above conjectures are false, what are the conditions (necessary and/or sufficient) on the integer values of $a, b$ such that the above conjectures are true.

Comment: $x_1=0, x_2=b$ surely works, integer values too.

Comment: @Macavity I have added more details and boundary conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Write your original equation as:

$$\left(x_1-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-x_2^2=\frac{a^2}{4}-b^2$$

$$\left(x_1-\frac{a}{2}-x_2\right)\left(x_1-\frac{a}{2}+x_2\right)=\frac{a^2}{4}-b^2$$

... so you could equate, for example $x_1-x_2-\frac{a}{2}=1$, $x_1+x_2-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a^2}{4}-b^2$ and get a rational solution for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

So the answer to your question is yes, there is an infinite number of solutions for each choice of integers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I have added more details and boundary conditions.

Comment: @ShivaKintali Then you should also have $2b>a$ for the square root to make sense.

Comment: Yes. I have added it now.